# Magento admin change order state

Tags: magento

How to change the order status from the Magento admin panel manually. Is there any way to change the order status? i could not find this in 1.7.0.2 version. Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Comment: This post will shed some light on the status topics.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17587916/magento-payment-workflow-and-event-order-paid

Answer (score 6):

Take a look @ Magento: [Difference between order states and statuses](http://ka.lpe.sh/2012/04/21/magento-order-state-vs-status/)

Each 'State' may have multiple 'Statuses'

'State' are normally change internally by the system during certain events.

- When you place on order using cash/check the magento will put the order in a 'New' state (if using credit card that automatically authorize and capture then it will set to 'processing')
- when you invoice the order magento will change the state to 'processing'
- when you ship the order it will change the the state to 'complete'.

Without more information it is hard to determining what your trying to accomplish, you may want to create custom 'status' instead and change them in admin order view

Answer (score 0):

In the admin->sales->order page. You will see the list of orders. You can change order status by using the Actions dropdown.
On the other hand, in specific order, you can change order status at the "Comments History" section.
I hope this information can help you.

Answer (score -2):

To change the order status you must first enable order auto complete

**system->config->sales**

Disable Order Auto Complete set it to **No**,then go to the order in sales and click **create invoice** on the upper right handside then scroll the page to the bottom and click sent comment once your done with that click ship and click submit comment and the order status will change to complete.